# Variable which will tell how much amount remaining to achieve free shipping?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2

How can I get this ,  Only x amount remaining to get free shipping ? Is there any functionality available ? As My site will give free shipping above 50$

Comment: Why is this on hold? I think question is clear and not that broad as well.

Comment: yes @Anime I was thinking same.  Same question is already answered in  Magento 1 already exist but not in magento 2

Answer (score 3):

You have to a create a simple method for it - e.g in helper.

1. Create a helper file:

> YOUR/MODULE/helper/data.php
>
> ```
> const FREE_SHIPPING = 'carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal';
>
> /**
>  * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
>  */
> protected $_scopeConfig;
>
> /**
>  * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
>  */
> protected $_cart;
>
> /**
>  * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
>  */
> protected $_pricingHelper;
>
> /**
>  * Data constructor.
>  *
>  * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
>  * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
>  * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
>  * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $_pricingHelper
>  */
> public function __construct(
>     \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
>     \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
>     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
>     \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper
> )
> {
>     parent::__construct($context);
>     $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
>     $this->_cart = $cart;
>     $this->_pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
> }
>
> /**
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function countFreeShipping()
> {
>     $result = null;
>     $minPrice = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::FREE_SHIPPING, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
>     $totalPrice = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
>     if ($minPrice && $totalPrice) {
>         $finalPrice = $minPrice - $totalPrice;
>         if ($finalPrice > 0) {
>             $result = $this->_pricingHelper->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
>         }
>     }
>     return $result;
> }
> ```

2. Than in your template (e.g in shopping cart above coupon) use it

> YOUR/MODULE/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/coupon.phtml

```
/** @var \YOUR\MODULE\Helper\Data $_checkoutHelper */
$_yourHelper = $this->helper('YOUR\MODULE\Helper\Data');
?>
<?php if($_yourHelper->countFreeShipping()) : ?>
<div class="discount-info-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><span> <?= __('You still need %1 for free standard shipping', $_yourHelper->countFreeShipping()); ?>!</span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

P.S - sorry for formating but somthing it's wrong here and I can't format this code correctly

Comment: thank you for reply , I have to make helper in vendor ? Or I can In my theme ?

Comment: Point 2. in your theme, point 1 -> You have to create your module in app/code

Comment: I dont want to change in vendor , SO I will make  a module in app/code then  I will do point 2 in  app/design/frontend/Magento_checkout/...  ?

Comment: I dont know too much about module creation , just tell me I have to some thing in helper according to module name or just paste it as it is ?

Comment: In Google you can find many information how to create a custom module / custom helper

Comment: Have you created theme? If so then you can do it via objectManager as well.

Comment: I am using paid theme ultimo ,  @Anime

Comment: Okay, but the way of @K.Maliszewski is considered best practice. Try it ,creating module is ver simple. I can't answer coz it's in hold . Best of luck.

Comment: @Anime you have working solution ?  maybe I am making mistake creating helper. If you can guide ?